# Rows to Columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am currently trying to convert a table of rows into a view of columns in an MS SQL Database.  My data is currently in a table like so:

```
ID  OID  Field                                 DataType   Value   Archived
==  ===  ====================================  ========   =====  =========
1   13   E21FC1EC-A6D9-43E2-8C8E-0F2935A7EF68  string     Hello  0
2   13   6BBDE7FA-6F7A-4319-899B-2DF0E6610FA9  string     World  1
3   13   91BB8616-43CD-48EC-97CD-5813B67770ED  int        1      0
4   13   A98D43C3-0A9C-4173-8ECE-29AAAE1D973E  int        2      1
5   13   92BB0DFF-EEAF-4A07-A65A-C3A1E1220F60  boolean    true   0
6   13   1AEE3D08-5F09-4A18-80AC-344E03F6AD7B  boolean    false  0
```

My results set should contain a row for each unique OID, and a column for each field in the above table. The value column should be the cell value. An example would be: (I have reduced the number of columns in this example):

```
OID E21FC1EC-A6D9-43E2-8C8E-0F2935A7EF68 6BBDE7FA-6F7A-4319-899B-2DF0E6610FA9 91BB8616-43CD-48EC-97CD-5813B67770ED 
=== ==================================== ==================================== ====================================
13  Hello                                World                                1
```

I have tried various approaches, including CASE, PIVOTS etc but I can't quite figure it out. Any solution should work with SQL Server 2005+.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: "have tried various approaches, including CASE, PIVOTS" - suggest you post an attempt.

Comment: @DavidMuir: Have you tried using a matrix in SSRS?

Comment: Pivoting is probably the way to go. The easiest way to come up to speed on pivot tables is to muck around with Excel. Create a regular table, with labels for column headers, and use the Pivot Table wizard located under the data menu to help you make various pivot tables.
MS Access has a way to invoke Excel's pivot table tool built into it, so it's easy to start with a relational table and concoct a pivot table.  I don't know about MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing here a good example of Dynamic Pivoting:

> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDetail](  [PK_User] [bigint] NOT NULL,
>     [FK_Property] [int] NOT NULL,   [PropValue] varchar NOT NULL )
>   ON [PRIMARY]
>
> GO INSERT [dbo].[UserDetail] ([PK_User], [FK_Property], [PropValue])
>   VALUES (1, 1, N'Jitendra') INSERT [dbo].[UserDetail] ([PK_User],
>   [FK_Property], [PropValue]) VALUES (1, 2, N'Garg') INSERT
>   [dbo].[UserDetail] ([PK_User], [FK_Property], [PropValue]) VALUES (2,
>   1, N'Praveen') INSERT [dbo].[UserDetail] ([PK_User], [FK_Property],
>   [PropValue]) VALUES (2, 2, N'Mehta') INSERT [dbo].[UserDetail]
>   ([PK_User], [FK_Property], [PropValue]) VALUES (2, 3, N'Udaipur')
>
> GO
>
> ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[usp_Pivot] (  @UserId As INT ) As DECLARE
>   @Query As VARCHAR(MAX)
>
> DECLARE @StrColumn As VARCHAR(MAX) = '' SELECT @StrColumn = CASE
>   @StrColumn WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE @StrColumn + ',' END+ 'ISNULL(['+
>   CAST(FK_Property AS VARCHAR(10)) +'],'''') AS Col' + CAST(FK_Property
>   AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM dbo.UserDetail(NoLock) WHERE PK_User = @UserId
>
> DECLARE @StrIn As VARCHAR(MAX) = '' SELECT @StrIn = CASE @StrIn WHEN
>   '' THEN '' ELSE @StrIn + ',' END+ '['+ CAST(FK_Property AS
>   VARCHAR(10)) +']' FROM dbo.UserDetail(NoLock) WHERE PK_User = @UserId
>
> SET @Query =  'SELECT * FROM  (   SELECT      PK_User As UserId,      '+
>   @StrColumn +'     FROM    (       SELECT              PK_User,FK_Property,PropValue
>         FROM dbo.UserDetail(NoLock) WHERE PK_User = ' + CAST(@UserId AS
>   VARCHAR(10)) + '  ) p     PIVOT   (       MAX (PropValue)         FOR FK_Property IN
>   ('+ @StrIn +')    ) AS pvt )X'
>
> PRINT @Query EXEC (@Query) GO

You can modify this as per your requirement.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx